# Storing values of multiple dynamic textboxes to array

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms, textbox

Textboxes are generated dynamically

```
public void createtxtbox(int d)
{
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    txtbox = new TextBox[d*d];

    for (int u = 0; u < txtbox.Count(); u++)
    {
        txtbox[u] = new TextBox();
    }


    for (int i = 0; i < txtbox.Length; i++)
    {
        int name = i + 1;
        txtbox[i].Name = "TXT" + name.ToString();
        txtbox[i].Location = new Point(42 + (x * 31), 47 + (y * 21));
        txtbox[i].Visible = true;
        txtbox[i].Size = new Size(30, 20);
        txtbox[i].MaxLength = 1;
        txtbox[i].TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
        this.Controls.Add(txtbox[i]);

        x++;
        if (x == d)
        {
            x = 0; y++;
        }


        }
    }
```

In the form the user inputs values into them and which would then be stored later in an array at exit.

The only way I know of storing textbox values to string:

```
txtbx = textBox.Text
```

**EDIT:
answered it**

found what went wrong with the code
thought this method was just returning null values but it was not...

```
private void txtboxtostring()
        {
            txtbx = new string[txtbox.Length];
            for (int i = 0; i < txtbox.Length; i++)
                txtbx[i]= txtbox[i].Text;      
        }
```

when button is clicked array would be passed to class

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //try
            //{
                txtboxtostring();
                create = new CreateClass(title, name);
                create.Createfile(txtbx);


                this.Close();
                Menu menu = new Menu();
                menu.Show();
            //}

            //catch
            //{
            //    MessageBox.Show("Something went wrong");
            //}
        }
```

would be evaluated/assigned here in this method in the class

```
 private void Popvals(string[] t)
        {
            vals = new string [t.Length];
            for (int i = 0; i<t.Length; i++)
            { vals[i] = t[i]; }
        }
```

and I'm free to do what I want with the values...
well thanks to everyone that helped

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: whats the question here?

Comment: Why can't you use txtbx = txtbox[i].Text?

Comment: Isn't `txtbox` your array of `textbox` ?

Comment: I think I need more time pondering on this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string[] values = txtbox.Select(x => x.Text).ToArray();
```

Comment: well thanks for helping but I did it this way instead, site won't allow me to answer my own question